# ImageMagick Crop Tall image into A4 PDF pages with same width dynamic height

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

how can we make a tall-dynamicheight-screenshot.png into onefile.pdf with multiple pages in A4 so it could be readable when its printed?

example like this :

[image]

**into A4 pages like**

[image]

**so when we print it would be like**

[image]

**not like (unreadable)**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe good enough for a crude first approach - it doesn't look for good places (white space) to divide the pages along though, so it slices through the image at the bottom of your first page:

```
convert article.jpg -resize 2480x -crop 2480x3508 +repage result.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: sliced image is good, but why the whitespace at page 2? is there a logic behind it? or is it becouse of center?

Comment: I do not get white space at the top of page 2. As Mark says, it cuts through the image and starts the image on the second page at the top. The preview does not represent what I get. What is your version of ImageMagick and on what platform? What is your version of libjpeg? I tested on IM 6.9.9.4 and IM 7.0.6.4 and don't get any white space. For IM 7, use magick in place of convert.

Comment: Oh, I see, it is centred on the page. Try adding `-gravity north` just before the output filename. If that doesn't work, try adding `-gravity north -background white -extent 2480x3508` before the output filename.

Answer (score 1):

In imagemagick you can crop to multiple pages. But it depends upon whether you want to keep your original size or resize the width to correspond to A4. The A4 file dimensions are 595x842.

If you want to keep the original dimensions and create a multipage PDF, then you will get 12 pages at your original resolution

```
convert V0twr.jpg -crop 595x842 +repage onefile1.pdf
```

If you want to resize to the width of an A4 and then crop, then you will get 2 pages at reduced resolution.

```
convert V0twr.jpg -resize 595x -crop 595x842 +repage onefile2.pdf
```

You can choose some other in-between resolution for your resize, if you want as a compromise, say twice the width of A4 = 2*595 = 1180

Comment: hmm tried it but why its not croping vertally from top? but when i tried with the repage still the same problem with white space

Comment: What is your IM version and platform? The use of -crop without offsets may be more current than a very old version of ImageMagick. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile. Is your input image jpg or some other format such as png. PNG may already have a virtual-canvas with offsets. So you could add +repage right after reading the input.

Comment: 7.0.5-5 Q16 x86_64 2017-04-25, i see yes theres a white space maybe becouse of centering

Comment: Hi, if anybody is still around, I wish to resize to A4, but it seems I lose resolution (writing is poorly readable). Is there a way to fix?

Comment: If you start with a raster image (JPG, PNG, etc) and enlarge it to A4 it will get blurry even if you save it in a PDF. What exactly are your trying to do and with what type of starting and ending images and what sizes?